# Items in ListView not long clickable after setting click listener in getView()

Tags: android, android-listview

I've searched around and have not come out with a solution (maybe not using the correct keywords).

So, I've a custom ListView which its item can be dragged around when the item is long clicked. Within its item, there's an ImageView and LinearLayout containing two TextViews. Actions are done when the LinearLayout or ImageView is clicked.

To do this, I've use setOnItemLongClickListener on my DragListView which extends ListView, to initiate drag action, and onInterceptTouchEvent to manage the drag action.

Then, I have built a custom adapter extending BaseAdapter and overrided its getView() to implement the child items in the row. The LinearLayout and ImageView have been setOnClickListener.

The problem is, the LinearLayout and ImageView are able to do their stuff, but the onItemLongClick isn't called.

The listener inside getView();

```
    holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//Do something
}
```

For item long click (drag initiator)

```
setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {              

    @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
    //Do something
    }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is on you list item view? Which controls are you using?

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand the question. If I get it right, my layout is more or less same with the one shown [here](http://www.geekmind.net/2009/11/android-custom-list-item-with-nested.html), except that my listview have setOnItemLongClick

Comment: @AlvinThen Hey, can you provide the code for this functionality to drag item on long press and handle the click event of each view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a gesture detector is one of ways to handle events.
Usually, however, a gesture detector is used when we want to detect a gesture not a long-press.

The reason why onItemLongClick isn't called is that onClickListener might consume a touch event. 
In that reason, if you want to handle onItemLongClick, intercept touch event and dispatch it to views you want to handle.

You can find more details following link. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Comment: hmmm do you mean that in my custom listview, i override intercepttouchevent, then dispatch the touch event to onitemlongclick? the thing i don't understand is I don't know how to dispatch the touch event to onitemlongclick first as it doesn't accept motionevent as parameter

Comment: Anyway, did you do setLongClickable(true); on each items in getView()?

Comment: Hey great, setLongClickable at convertView does the magic! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just found out the solution myself.
Instead of using onItemLongClickListener, I create a gesture detector to detect for long press. Then I override dispatchTouchEvent and force to scan for long press first, then return super.dispatchTouchEvent and the other following touch events.
Suggestions are still welcomed!

Comment: @James i'm sorry but i do not own the code anymore. if you are facing the exact same problem as me, try setLongClickable(true) at convertView

Comment: Well if anyone has come here in search for the solution then I would recommend to get the event in the `getView()` of adapter corresponding to the `CustomAdapter`, and try finding 'customView.onLong...' or 'customView.onClick...' use both together both will work properly.