# Set selection on longClick?

Tags: java, android

How can I set a long-clicked item as selected?
This does not work (item does not maintain selected when clicked):

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {
                listView.setSelection(position);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: setLongClickable(true)?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855541/items-in-listview-not-long-clickable-after-setting-click-listener-in-getview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to use a multi-select list, make sure you flag it as such:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

If it's a single-select list, you still need to flag it as a "choice mode" list, as opposed to one where clicking just performs an action, not selects the item.

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

And since you've got the view you want to select being passed in as a parameter, you don't need to set by position, you can set by the view instead, like so:

```
view.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using
`view.setSelected(true);`
If the background of your listview items has selected state - this will change the background to this selected state.